# mobile vision Qrcode Call intent multiple time

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a **QrScanner** apps for scanning using google mobile vision. App is simple like scannig a Qrcode , app decode the Qrcode ,deliver it to result class and result shows in the Result layout. But the problem is When im trying to Scan Qrcode , Some how it call result class multiple time ... heres my MainActivity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
SurfaceView surfaceView;
BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
CameraSource cameraSource;
final int RequestCameraID = 1001;
BoxDetector boxDetector;




@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    surfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
    Casting();
}

private void Casting() {
   barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
    boxDetector = new BoxDetector(barcodeDetector, 300, 300);

    if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry couldn't setup the detector", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(MainActivity.this, boxDetector)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedFps(30)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 720)
            .build();

    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},RequestCameraID);
                return;
            }

            try {
                cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();

        }
    });


    boxDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {
        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodeSparseArray = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if(barcodeSparseArray.size()!=0){
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        cameraSource.release();
                        barcodeDetector.release();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Result",barcodeSparseArray.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        Casting();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

public void cS() {
    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
    boxDetector = new BoxDetector(barcodeDetector, 300, 300);

    if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry couldn't setup the detector", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(MainActivity.this, boxDetector)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedFps(30)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 720)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestCameraID: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

BoxDetector Code is:

```
public class BoxDetector extends Detector {
private Detector mDelegate;
private int mBoxWidth, mBoxHeight;



BoxDetector(Detector delegate, int boxWidth, int boxHeight) {
    mDelegate = delegate;
    mBoxWidth = boxWidth;
    mBoxHeight = boxHeight;

}

public SparseArray detect(Frame frame) {

    int width = frame.getMetadata().getWidth();
    int height = frame.getMetadata().getHeight();
    int right = ((width / 2) + (mBoxHeight / 2)) -150 ;
    int left = ((width / 2) - (mBoxHeight / 2)) - 150;
    int bottom = ((height / 2) + (mBoxWidth / 2));
    int top = ((height / 2) - ((mBoxWidth) / 2));

    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(frame.getGrayscaleImageData().array(), ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] jpegArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length);

    Frame croppedFrame =
            new Frame.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(bitmap)
                    .setRotation(frame.getMetadata().getRotation())
                    .build();


    return mDelegate.detect(croppedFrame);

}

public void run(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public boolean setFocus(int id) {
    return mDelegate.setFocus(id);
}
```

}

Thats it Thank You!

Comment: You are calling Casting() whenever you receive detection, which will create another boxdetector instance. Also, when barcode detector is not operational, you should exit the method.

Comment: After remove casting from threds apps getting crashed..